# Cant connect to Microsoft SQL Server in Anypoint Studio

Tags: sql-server, anypoint-studio

I try to connect from Anypoint Studio to Microsoft SQL Server but I found this error:
[image]

This is my config:

```
<db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="b8b71572-d93f-4fbb-b248-67b553d47401" >
        <db:mssql-connection host="localhost" port="1433" user="charaz" password="Gundam123" databaseName="gundam" />
    </db:config>
```

Do I miss or messed up anything here? Thanks

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: port 1433 is probably wrong, run sql server configuration manager and check ports

Comment: Thanks for the info @aled I already edit the post

Comment: Also please add the error detail as text.

Comment: What version (and edition) of Microsoft SQL Server do you have installed? If you check in SQL Server Configuration Manager, does it have the TCP/IP protocol enabled? What TCP/IP port(s) is it listening on?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Icheck the tcp/ip and i put the wrong port number, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I check the manager and i put a wrong port number, its not 1433. I thought the default port for local is 1433, Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).